# Configure contribution module with OpenCV 3.0 by CMake

Tags: configuration, cmake, opencv3.0

I am trying to configure the contribution file with OpenCV 3.0 to use SIFT and SURF algorithm. I am following this with CMake-gui; https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib

I set up followings on the CMake GUI; 
where is the source code: C:/opencv/sources
where to build binaries: C:/opencv/sources/modules/core

But whenever try to do this, it returns following error;

The CXX compiler identification is unknown
The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/opencv/sources/modules/core/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/opencv/sources/modules/core/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Could anyone please help me on this to go forward?

Thank you so much! Much appreciated.
Best,

Comment: Your C++ compiler is not found. You can set it by passing a value to the CMAKE_C_COMPILER variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SIFT and SURF algorithm, better download opencv-2.10.I personally felt comfortable while working with this package. You can get [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and follow the [installation process](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html). Be sure that you have the  dependencies are prior installed.

Comment: yeah it might be another solution in this situation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you on? Linux? Windows? 
If Linux, check if you have gcc compiler installed on your system. 
If Windows, it depends on the compiler you are using, if Visual Studio is installed then you are asked to select the version of the Visual Studio since you are using Cmake GUI.

If you are on Linux system follow this link to properly install OpenCV
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html